# error TS2741: Property is missing in type

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, angular7

In file models/User.model.ts (see below) I tried to set a method isEqual as shown in code below. 
Could someone correct my code ?

file models/User.model.ts:

```
export class User {
    constructor(
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string,
    ) {}

    isEqual (other : User): boolean {
    return other === this;
    }
}
```

file services/user.service.ts :

```
import { User } from '../models/User.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class UserService {

    private users: User[] = [
    {
        firstName: 'William',
        lastName: 'Jones'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }
    ];
```

...

ERROR in services/user.service.ts(7,2): error TS2741: Property 'isEqual' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string;}' but required in type 'User'.

Comment: You can't just say `{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }`is a `User`, because it's not.  You need to `new User('john', 'doe');`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips that's very unfortunate, and one of my frustrations with TypeScript. Other languages have no problem handling that syntax

Comment: @nuzzolilo what other languages support creating an object without specifying/calling the constructor?

Comment: @ErikPhilips putting aside the semantics of whether the default constructor is called (which isn't the issue in question): JS, C#, F#, Java, C99, C++20 (via designated initializers), Python, and now TS via Partial<T> are just some ones I can think of. I added an answer showing how to do this with TS if changing the constructor is an option.

Comment: @nuzzolilo I would beg to differ on the default constructor.  The [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) functionally does many things that are not possible without calling new.  As with most if not all related languages in your post, new is *required* for constructing a user defined class.  While there may be ways to avoid the constructor being called (like c#), it is it rarely used except for some major exceptions.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't think anyone is complaining about having to type out "new". The issue here is whether you have to craft the constructor to explicitly handle every field in the class! The benefit of using an object literal instead of the constructor syntax is that you get to specify that you want all fields to be the default, except for whatever you are explicitly specifying in that literal, not having to think about the order of the fields in the constructor. In C#, the default constructor is still called when instantiating an object via a literal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specifying that the parameter you are taking in function `isEqual` should be of type or model as `{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }`, this shows you just need to pass data in this format.

Answer (score 5):

> ERROR in services/user.service.ts(7,2): error TS2741: Property 'isEqual' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string;}' but required in type 'User'.

This is because in your class definition you have the function declared `isEqual`, but in your list of users you only have the `firstName` and `lastName` but not the associated function and the type of users is `Users`.

```
{
  firstName: 'William',
  lastName: 'Jones'
},
```

As mentioned in the comments you could use the `new ()` to make a new `User` which should also include the function.

```
public exampleUser = new User("William", "Jones");
```

This could then in turn be used in an array of `Users`

```
public users: Users =  [ this.exampleUser ];
```

Comment: I do not understand where in the code I should write this new User. Could you be more explicit ?

Comment: you could go with public users: Users = [ new User("john", "Doe"),  new User("william", "jones")]; etc :-)

Comment: did this help you fix your issue?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the method isEqual is correctly interpreted. I did as you said : `public wj = new User ('William', 'Jones');
    public ep = new User (''John", "Doe");
    public users = [this.wj, this.jd];`

Comment: I do not know how to make a vote nor how to make a new line in a comment. Sorry. Anyway you help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since support for `Partial<T>` was added, you can now change the constructor of User to the below, and you should be able to initialize the object by specifying a partial hash of keys and values (as you tried to do above).

```
constructor(init?:Partial<User>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
}
```

From the documentation (currently at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt):

> Constructs a type with all properties of T set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you won't prefer this usage, but you can make the method **optional**, if you do not need `isEqual` for the items in the array.

Adding question mark(?) to the method name

```
isEqual?(other: User): boolean
```

However if you need `isEqual` for all items, then this solution won't help you as I said in the beginning. By this usage, when you try to use `isEqual` method it will give `undefined` error.